# Altium place string (letter with macron)

Tags: altium, silkscreen

I am looking for a way to place a macron in top of a letter on the silk screen. in Altium i have only 3 fonts to chose from default??, Sans Serif and Serif non of them supports macron for capital letters, but i have seen this on many locations so is the only way to place a line separately over each letter ?
eg.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select any TrueType font you have on your computer and use whatever weird symbols you like. The choices of sans-serif and serif apply only to stroke fonts. Using TT fonts (potentially) sacrifices portability if you need to edit the file on another computer that doesn't have that TT font installed it won't work, and it will make your Gerber files bigger (but that's not really a problem in 2015).

[image]

I don't know of a way to put an overbar over a set of characters like you would on a net label (for example R\E\S\E\T\ for inverted reset).

Comment: I normally put an overbar drawing a line tool, and then assign a group with the text so I can move the word+overbar around freely.

Comment: @cjferes Unlike Adobe Illustrator and most graphics programs group = 'union' in Altium terms, I believe.

Comment: yeah, that's the concept, but the idea is the same and it's simple (haven't used Altium in a while)